# My PostgreSQL 10 server is crashing after I try and create a new database and can't restart

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to using PostgreSQL and I'm running into a lot of issues just trying to get it started. For some reason, when I try to create a new database, the server crashes and can't restart. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this from happening? I'm also using Ubuntu 18.04 that I installed on my Windows 10 operating system.

I've been following this tutorial: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/PostgreSQL_GetStarted.html

Here's what happened:

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE courtney;
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
!> \q
```

When trying to restart it:

```
$ sudo service postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 10 database server                                                                 * Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log -s -o  -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf"  exited with status 1:
2019-05-05 13:03:27.879 DST [2502] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2019-05-05 13:03:27.973 DST [2502] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2019-05-05 13:03:28.189 DST [2503] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-05-05 11:18:20 DST
2019-05-05 13:03:28.189 DST [2503] PANIC:  could not flush dirty data: Function not implemented
2019-05-05 13:03:28.189 DST [2502] LOG:  startup process (PID 2503) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2019-05-05 13:03:28.189 DST [2502] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2019-05-05 13:03:28.204 DST [2502] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

Comment: Do you already have any postgres databases?  (If so, this is not a good place to be in, if not, you can just start again).

Comment: Hi davidgo, thanks for responding. This was the first database I was trying to create, I haven't made any others before. I uninstalled PostgresQL and reinstalled it and tried again, but still had the same error.

Comment: I'm also using Ubuntu 18.04 if that makes a difference.